# Unable to connect remote Oracle DB in java stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to connect to a remote oracle database in java stored procedure in a traditional way. I am able to call the java stored procedure successfully. But I receive the exception "Missing In or Out parameter at Index 1" while making the connection. I am not sure how this error is related to making a connection in any way. But I don't have any other piece of code in java.

```
try{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  


Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:servicename","user","pwd"); 
}catch(Exception e){
  //(Missing In or Out parameter at index 1) 
  //logged the error in the local database table
}
```

Can someone please help me where I need to make a change to connect to another oracle database.

Comment: Looks like your stored procedure expecting parameter, check your invocation code

Comment: This is not a connection problem. This is an execution problem. You may not have certain set parameters. Can you enter the declaration of your procedure and lines of execution?

Comment: lakshman, Khairyi.. thanks for the reply. I don't see any error when I call the procedure. But the problem is within the java program while making a connection. I captured the exception and inserted it in local DB. And the error is so unrelated.

Comment: give the complete code, especially the parameter definitions... If it has an in-out parameter and this is the entirety of your code block, yeah, it is missing an out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Connection URL for `servicename` and `sid` differ.

**Format:**

With SERVICE NAME: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/ServiceName`

With SID: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID`